# Python AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'

Tags: python

**returns an error**

(venv) C:\Users\stast\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\ManagunBot>bot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\stast\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\ManagunBot\bot.py", line 19, in 
@bot.command()
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from config import settings



prefix = settings['PREFIX']
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['PREFIX'], intents=discord.Intents.all())
bot.remove_command('help')

bot = discord.Client(activity=discord.Game(name='!help')) # активность бота (во что играет)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Бот успешно запущен!') # Вывод готовности в консоль


@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Pong")

client.run (settings['TOKEN'])
```

Comment: it should be `bot.run(settings['TOKEN'])` and also, remove `bot = discord.Client(activity=discord.Game(name='!help')) # активность бота (во что играет)`

Comment: I see that you are assigning `bot` variable twice. Is this correct?

Comment: When asking a question, try to contextualize people to the problem you are having, show what you have tried and use tags that could improve the reach of your question, for example `discord`.

Answer (score 1):

You replaced your `commands.Bot()` with `discord.Client()`. Try this instead:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from config import settings


prefix = settings['PREFIX']
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['PREFIX'], intents=discord.Intents.all())
bot.remove_command('help')


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Бот успешно запущен!') # Вывод готовности в консоль
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='!help')) # активность бота (во что играет)


@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Pong")

bot.run(settings['TOKEN'])
```